# Validate Slot Filling Input

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using dialog flow node library for fulfillment. I want to validate the user input in slot filling fulfillment. For example if I have an intent which requires following parameters like name, phone, email, address, pin code, date of call and date of time.

Now my validation rule is pin code should be 6 digit Indian postal code. So how can I re-prompt the user for re-entering the postal code and save all previous filled parameter in the same context?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use fulfillment to validate the inputs. As part of the fulfillment, you can store the parameters, as they've been accepted and validated, in a Context, as you suggest. You should use different names for the context parameters than the slot parameters, since prompted parameters will overwrite context parameters, possibly with empty strings.

If a value isn't validated, your fulfillment should just send back a prompt asking for the value again. You may also want to set an additional context which will enable response specific Intents for that value.

Remember - Intents represent *what the user says*, not how you handle what they say.

Comment: don't know what are you saying but  I have done this by deleting the current executing intent context and by making new context which hold my hold old valid values and invoke current intent by an event. When that event trigger i have set the default value of parameter in dialog flow from new context name.

Comment: @AshishGarg can you share the code for more understanding of how you handle this issue